# Python multiprocessing process doesn't run

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

First of all, it should probably be mentioned that I'm fairly new to programming, and that I'm using Python 3.2.5. I'm trying to create a game that connects to and pings a server with regular intervals. At first, I tried to simply bundle this right into the game's main loop, with the result that said loop froze for the duration of the ping (My connection is slow, and I don't want this to inhibit gameplay as the game doesn't depend on the server at all - It just needs to ping it to keep the session open in order to later register a final score).

Getting to the point, I figured I'd try using a secondary loop for all server-related code, which brought me to multiprocessing. My current idea is to keep an infinite loop running, and feeding it with tasks through a queue. It'll then return info on wether said tasks were successful or not through queue, and the game can run smoothly. I stripped it down to the following for testing, and nothing gets printed. I would obviously like to know why.

(I'm guessing a lot of clever people have better ideas for how to do this. I'm all ears.)

```
import multiprocessing

def aFunction(q_in, q_out):
    while True:
        item = q_in.get()
        q_out.put("some info")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q_in = multiprocessing.Queue()
    q_out = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = aFunction, args = (q_in, q_out))

    p.start()
    q_in.put("some task here")

    while True:
        item = q_out.get()
        print(str(item))
```

Comment: Edited the OP to explain my thinking around those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320237/user) commented, you're not calling the `empty` method in the line `while q_out.empty == False`, you're just referencing it. You need to add a set of parentheses to make it a call: `while q_out.empty() == False`

That issue was causing your main process to never try to `get` any of the replies from your worker process, which is probably why you're not seeing the printed results in your testing.

Actually, while you're editing the line above, there is a style improvement to make: Use `not` rather than `== False`: `while not q_out.empty()`

Another style suggestion is to use `if items` rather than `if len(items) > 0`. If you know items is a collection, they have the same meaning.

Or, you could strip your loop way down to just processing a single item at a time, with no lists or checks for the queue being empty:

```
while True:
    item = q_out.get() # this will block until another item is available
    # do stuff with that single item here
```

If you need to pass several related items together, use a `tuple` or list, rather than passing them sequentially (which can't guarantee that they'll be received together, rather than split up between two passes on the worker process).

Comment: I misinterpreted @User quite a lot, it would seem. Regardless, this is all nice and helpful (modified the OP accordingly), but I'm still not getting any printed output.

Comment: I tested the code you currently have in the question and it prints `"some info"` as I'd expect. It does run forever, but that's not really a flaw in the multiprocessing code, it's simply that you only ever send one item through your queues and then deadlock when both queues are empty. If you have other things to do with your main loop, you could bring back the `while not q_out.empty()` loop or do a non-blocking `get` to avoid this.

Comment: God damn it, you're right. I'll call this a ghost in the machine, because I could've sworn it didn't print anything before. Anyhow, question resolved and thanks a bunch.

Comment: Using Python 2.7.5 won't a call to `q_out.get()` when it's empty stop the process from executing any further?